# Defining Ingress for k3s traefik

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, k3s, traefik-ingress

I am running k3s version 1.25.5 and I would like to define traefik as an ingress for one of the services defined through [an external helm chart](https://helm.camunda.io/). I am struggling to find the right ingress definition. I tried with the below yaml file but that gives an error stating

```
error: resource mapping not found for name: "c8-ingress" namespace: "" from "zeebe-traefik.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
```

This seems to be because of the an old apiVersion used in the yaml file. How to do it the right way?

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: c8-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: dev-zeebe-gateway
          servicePort: 26500
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `extensions/v1beta1` for the `apiVersion`? The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) says you should be using `networking.k8s.io/v1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is using an outdated Ingress definition. In v1.25.x you need to use the stable `networking.k8s.io/v1` API, as described [here](https://v1-25.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

It is also recommended to provide the fitting namespace. This is useful for documentation, but also required for [resource backends](https://v1-25.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#resource-backend). It will also avoid adding `-n YOURNAMESPACE` to every `kubectl apply`.

In your case, this may look something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: c8-ingress
  namespace: YOURNAMESPACE
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: dev-zeebe-gateway
                port:
                  number: 26500
```

I hope this helps to solve your issue.

In many cases, you can run `kubectl explain RESOURCE` to get useful links and resources for a given api-resource.

Comment: Great thanks. This configuration worked straight-away!

Comment: Happy to read this. Good luck by digging your way into kubernetes.